# bash - how to find and zip files that contain a string?

Tags: bash

I want to zip all files contain string '12345' to file mylog.zip.
Using grep -l i can find the file and use this command but it does not zip the files.

```
grep -l 12345  *  |  zip  mylog.zip;
```

I try command

```
grep -l 12345  *
```

It found the files. Issue is how to pass this to zip.

Comment: grep -r -l 12345 ./ | zip files.zip -@

Answer (score 4):

```
find -name "*12345*" -type f -print | zip name.zip -@
```

OR

```
find -name "*12345*" -type f -exec zip name.zip {} +
```

Comment: @hellio6 `man zip`: _-@ file lists.  If a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS], zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead of from the command line_

Answer (score 1):

Another using bash `for` loop. Add proper quoting around variables if needed. In this example I grep for `a` in a bunch of files:

```
$ for f in *.txt; do grep -q a $f; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then zip my.zip $f ; fi ; done
  adding: test1.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: test3.txt (stored 0%)
```

Written open:

```
for f in *.txt
do 
    grep -l a $f
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then 
        zip my.zip $f
    fi
done
```

Comment: you can even use `grep -q`

Comment: @AkshayHegde Thanks. `-l` was a leftover from another experiment.